# Warning: Illegal string offset 'target' in typo3/sysext/lang/Classes/LanguageService.php

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x, typo3-6.2.x

I'm updating a project from 4.5 to 6.2.9

One of my backend module shows this warning in core module. This is the area calls to the language module.

```
 $this->MOD_MENU = Array (
     "function" => Array (
         "1" => $LANG->getLL("function1"),
         "2" => $LANG->getLL("function2"),    
         "3" => $LANG->getLL("function3"),
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\ErrorHandler::handleError(2, "Illegal string offset 'target'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of research and finding. A small line of mistake I could find in my index.php in my module directory [mod/index.php].

I've included locallang.php file using

```
require 'locallang.php';
```

When I replace that with typo3 API function $GLOBALS['LANG']->includeLLFile it has been fixed.

```
$GLOBALS['LANG']->includeLLFile("EXT:extension_directory/mod1/locallang.php");
```